# glue to fix rubber gasket on kettle

Tags: repair, water, adhesive, caulking

I have a Sunbeam electrical kettle that started leaking.  I took it apart and found a crack in one of the rubber gasket/grommet pieces that hold the plastic water reservoir in place on the metal kettle base.  I tried ordering a replacement one and was told that it wasn't possible (they don't have a code for that part, or some such nonsense).

So, the options are:

- use some sort of glue to fix the crack in the gasket
- toss out the gasket and seal around the hole with something like caulk or glue

My problem with either option is knowing what glue/sealant to use that would be appropriate for something holding drinking water and that frequently goes back and forth between 20C and 100C.

Here's a link to the kettle in question: http://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/red-chrome-kettle-bvsbkt3234r-033/6000065495084

**Edit:**
I have a small tube of Krazy Glue...  Would that be safe?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you can simply re-order a gasket from the manufacturer? Many of those highly replaceable parts are for sale. My second thought is gasket paper/material. It is commonly sold in sheets, and you can usually use the old broken one to trace like a template.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk - **"I tried ordering a replacement one and was told that it wasn't possible (they don't have a code for that part, or some such nonsense)."**

Comment: @BrownRedHawk - The gasket is a little strange.. Maybe when I get home I can post a picture of it.  It's not flat.  However, maybe a simple flat one would do fine as a replacement.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you went through wal-mart for a replacement, I wasn't sure if you went to the manufacturer.

Comment: @BrownRedHawk - the manufacturer is pretty useless as far as replacement parts...  it seems like you can order the little filter screen that goes just inside the spout, anything else is not possible.